# heroku: can't connect to postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This suddenly started without any code or configuration changes:

```
$ heroku run rails c                                                                                                   [ruby-2.3.3]
Running rails c on ⬢ [myHerokuApp]... up, run.3249 (Hobby)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection timed out (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "ec2-107-20-164-164.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (107.20.164.164) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I discovered this after seeing the site was down with an Application Error, and checked the logs:

```
2016-12-17T14:31:44.366559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stevelehman.herokuapp.com request_id=83b9ace7-392e-4513-9905-7cd891248d01 fwd="54.162.238.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Looking for any insight :(  I'm worried that the database is "gone", but wondering how this could have happened without any code/config changes.

Comment: try this command  heroku restart -a app_name and tell me what happens

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari It restarts ok, but `heroku run rails c` still gives the same error